# In Scikit, what signifies if a parameter required?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm reading *Artificial Intelligence Using Python* and while working through an example I decided to inspect the sklearn package documentation based on one of the methods used in the book.  While looking at the documentation, I noticed there are two parameters for the `sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer` method which are threshold and copy.  The documentation shows the following: `class sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=0.0, copy=True)`

However in the example from the book we only used the threshold argument and not the copy argument which worked:

```
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import preprocessing 
input_data = np.array([[5.1, -2.9, 3.3], 
                       [-1.2, 7.8, -6.1], 
                       [3.9, 0.4, 2.1], 
                       [7.3, -9.9, -4.5]]) 
# Binarize data  
data_binarized = preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=2.1).transform(input_data) 
print("\nBinarized data:\n", data_binarized)
```

Once I'm done with the book I'd like to know how to navigate the documentation so does anyone know what symbolizes an unneeded parameter in the sklearn or scikit documentation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As you can see from the docs, neither is required as both parameters have default values.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Binarizer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, if the function definition specifies a value for a parameter, then that value acts as a default. Specifying a new value will overwrite the default value. However, the function can be called without overwriting any default value.

For example, if I define the following function:

```
def add_numbers(param_one=1, param_two=2):
    return param_one + param_two
```

Then, I can do the following:

```
>>> add_numbers()
3

>>> add_numbers(param_one=2)
4

>>> add_numbers(param_two=1)
2

>>> add_numbers(param_one=2, param_two=3)
5
```

In your case, your function call of preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=2.1) is equivalent to preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=2.1, copy=True).

*Note*: You can also define a function *without a default value* for one or all parameters. In this case, the function cannot be called without specifying a value for the parameter.

Ex.

```
def add_numbers(param_one, param_two=2):
    return param_one + param_two

>>> add_numbers()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add_numbers() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a function in the documentation that doesn't have default parameter.  In Python, are there always default parameters and if not can you share what a function would look like in the scikit documentation if there aren't default parameters?

Comment: All sklearn estimators have default values, but that is by no means a Python standard or requirement. From the sklearn library, GridsearchCV needs an estimator. That parameter has no default.  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html